# My OpenGl 3D Tetris game has square cubes, but they are vanishing to infinity in the background, what is wrong?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I am making a 3d Tetris game, I have defined my cubes in 3d, and set up a LookAt and a Frustum matrix to view the game.

The game works fine with a Orthographic matrix, but when I switch to Frustum all the cubes vanish to infinity to the background.

The Tetris pieces are all defined in the +,+ quadrant if you think of it like a Euclidian grid.

The pieces have length, width and height of 33.

I first have a matrix that centers the entire game to 0, 0 so the game is in all 4 quadrants, than I have a LookAt matrix that the camera is at 0,0,0 and looking at 0,0,0.

Then now if I have a orthographic matrix, it looks fine, but if I switch to a Frustum, it looks like the [image: attached picture.]

Here is an example of 1 of 4 cubes that make up a Tetris tile's vertices:

```
( 132, 660, 16.5, 1 )( 165, 660, 16.5, 1 )( 165, 693, 16.5, 1 )( 132, 660,     16.5, 1 )( 165, 693, 16.5, 1 )( 132, 693, 16.5, 1 )( 165, 660, 16.5, 1 )( 165, 660, -16.5, 1 )( 165, 693, -16.5, 1 )( 165, 660, 16.5, 1 )( 165, 693, -16.5, 1 )( 165, 693, 16.5, 1 )( 165, 660, -16.5, 1 )( 132, 660, -16.5, 1 )( 132, 693, -16.5, 1 )( 165, 660, -16.5, 1 )( 132, 693, -16.5, 1 )( 165, 693, -16.5, 1 )( 132, 660, -16.5, 1 )( 132, 660, 16.5, 1 )( 132, 693, 16.5, 1 )( 132, 660, -16.5, 1 )( 132, 693, 16.5, 1 )( 132, 693, -16.5, 1 )( 132, 660, -16.5, 1 )( 165, 660, -16.5, 1 )( 165, 660, 16.5, 1 )( 132, 660, -16.5, 1 )( 165, 660, 16.5, 1 )( 132, 660, 16.5, 1 )( 132, 693, 16.5, 1 )( 165, 693, 16.5, 1 )( 165, 693, -16.5, 1 )( 132, 693, 16.5, 1 )( 165, 693, -16.5, 1 )( 132, 693, -16.5, 1 )
```

Here is where I set up my matrices:

```
vec4 eye(0, 0, 17, 1.0);
vec4  at(0, 0, 0, 1.0 );
vec4  up( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

mat4  mv = LookAt( eye, at, up );

mat4 center;
// window is 400 x 720, translating the game
// to make the game center at the origin
center[0][3] = -200;
center[1][3] = -360;

mv = mv * center;

glUniformMatrix4fv( model_view, 1, GL_TRUE, mv );

mat4  p = Frustum(-200, 200, -360, 360, 1, 45);
```

If I change the Frustum to Ortho above the game looks like this: [image]

If I change the coordinates of the camera eye at all, the entire game visually messes up and doesn't make sense to why. Even if I move the camera up one pixel. This also happens in Ortho projection, and I don't understand why.

Comment: That's kind of what you should expect when you use a perspective projection and your cube spans ~75% of the distance from the near plane to the far plane. It's going to visibly stretch out and converge toward the vanishing point. I'd suggest you increase the distance between `near` and `far` when you create your frustum.

Comment: `vec4`? `mat4`? What API is that?

Comment: The API is from our textbook http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/

Comment: Changing the far plane does nothing to the game, it looks the same though. Should I define the cubes to be further out so I can set the near place further? Why does moving the eye point of the camera up even 1 or 2 units give very strange results, it has to be at 0,0 for anything to look slightly normal?

Comment: Does the Z axis point out of the screen or into the screen?

Comment: When defining the world, I assume the z-axis goes into the screen. Although after the perspective matrix I believe the coordinates get flipped?

Comment: When defining the world, I assume the z-axis goes into the screen. Although after the perspective matrix I believe the coordinates get flipped?

Comment: I changed the camera to be a z=50 and the changed the near plane to be 60-1000 and it looks more realistic.

But if I move the camera up to x=5 with those numbers, the game clips off the right side of the screen, do I need to increase the Furstum right and left?

Comment: Here is what it looks like now: http://imgur.com/cD0WArE

The game plays off the right side, and the cubes look like they are slightly transparent or the colors are strange. Would you happen to know what that is from?

Thank you guys so much!

Comment: Correction, I assumed the negative z axis in into the screen. But when giving parameters to the matrix functions, you give them as positive.

Comment: How would I make it so the cubes hold their shape? If I moved the camera around a real-world 3d cube game, the pieces wouldn't all stretch like they are. The pieces always look like they are facing the camera.